# HTML base tag equivalent for absolute path

Tags: html, path

Imagine a website located at `http://example.com/myWebsite/`.

I would like my absolute paths to point to `myWebsite` directory.

I know one can do it for relative links with the `base` tag, but I wish to keep the default behavior for relative links.

Is there something useful I can specify in head ?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what an absolute URL is. An absolute URL isn't relative to anything. You can't make a URL like `https://stackoverflow.com` or `https://www.google.com` be relative to your own domain. If you wish to keep the default behavior for relative URLs, just don't use the base element - it's not required.

Comment: @BoltClock I wish any resources requested with `/myPath/foo.ext` be understood as `http://example.com/myWebsite/myPath/foo.ext`

Comment: At the moment I need to have a baseUrl variable (== "http://example.com/myWebsite") to inject before every absolute path, but it feels wrong not having an option to specify it once somewhere

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://example.com/myWebsite/" target="_blank">
</head>
<body>

<p><img src="stickman.gif" width="24" height="39" alt="Stickman"> - 
Notice that we have only specified a relative address for the image. 
Since we have specified a base URL in the head section, the browser will 
look for the image at "http://example.com/myWebsite/stickman.gif".
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Use this

Comment: this will break relative links behavior. If I'm on `http://example.com/myWebsite/directory/index.html` any link like `./image.png` would translate to `http://example.com/myWebsite/image.png` instead of `http://example.com/myWebsite/directory/image.png`